# Don't allow user move, maximize or minimize form in c# and auto maximize form when it opens

Tags: winforms, minimize, maximize

I'm looking for code in c # in VB 2013 to prevent the user can't move, maximize and minimize a Form

This Form should be maximized when it opens.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started.

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.ControlBox = false;
```

All of these are properties you can set in the form properties menu.  You can either add them there or in your code somewhere.  These kill the menus and such and don't allow your user to minimize, maximize, of move a form (i.e. makes it splash screen).

You might want to add this if you don't just want to kill the menu -

```
private void Form1_Resize ( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    if ( this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized )
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whith this code I can mantain close button in the form? I only want to mantain close button.

Comment: Then do it this way: `this.MaximizeBox = false; this.MinimizeBox = false;  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

Comment: But it allow user drag and move the Form.

Comment: Right - I think that's a default function of that title bar.  I'm not sure if you can turn that off programmatically.  If you put that resize event I included in your code, it should take care of that, though (i.e. maximize the form if they click on the title bar).  Otherwise, maybe you could just blow away the title bar and just include a Form.Close() button on your form somewhere?